# Is it safe for me to delete this profile?

Tags: iphone, beta-seed-program

Can I delete the Apple beta program profile? I've signed up for the beta, and I want to get rid of it now that I'm on the official release. Is this ok to do? I'm on iPhone 6 running iOS 10.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's safe, when you delete it and restart your phone, you'll just get into the normal update cycle.